# How to copy product information to meta information in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, meta-tags

How it is possible to copy all the characteristics below massively?

- title -> meta title
- title -> meta keywords
- description -> meta description

Comment: Could it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To set meta information *on the fly* (w/o save to product) you can use this ... It sets product name to meta title/keywords and description to meta description:

> app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <your_module>
                <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
            </your_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <test>
                        <class>your_module/observer</class>
                        <method>setMetaData</method>
                   </test>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
public function setMetaData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $product = $observer->getProduct();

    $title = $product->getMetaTitle() ? $product->getMetaTitle() : $product->getName();
    $description = $product->getMetaDescription() ? $product->getMetaDescription() : $product->getDescription();
    $description = strip_tags($description);

    $product->setMetaTitle($title);
    $product->setMetaKeyword($title);
    $product->setMetaDescription($description);
}
```

You can also save this meta information to DB, but i use this (modified) on my own to still be able to filter products w/o meta data and set them manually later.

If you want it saved to product data, you can replace `catalog_controller_product_view` with `catalog_product_save_before` event.