# Editing a product's metadescription dynamically

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to make an automation that takes the web title of a product's page, and write this to the meta description section of the Magento's back end. How would that be posible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your "web title" is, but you can do it in this way. It will set the metadescription on product save to product name.

1. in `config.xml` add an observer to `catalog_product_save_before`

   ```
   <catalog_product_save_before>
       <observers>
           <some_alias>
               <type>model</type>
               <class>your_module/observer</class>
               <method>setMetaDescriptionFromProductName</method>
           </some_alias>
       </observers>
   </catalog_product_save_before>
   ```
2. add this to `Observer.php`

   ```
   public function setMetaDescriptionFromProductName(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       # adjust this to your needs
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       $product->setMetaDescription($product->getName());
       return $this;
   }
   ```

If you want to generate meta data on the fly (without saving to product) you can use `catalog_controller_product_view` event instead: see [How to copy product information to meta information in Magento 1.9.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176377/how-to-copy-product-information-to-meta-information-in-magento-1-9-2/176379#176379)